# WFFM form reloads form page upon successAction before redirecting to success page

Tags: wffm, multisite

Working with multi-site single instance Sitecore 8.1 U3 solution and WFFM of the same version, I have a page at `https://site//contact-us/` which contains an enquiry form configured to redirect to a success page upon submitting. The success page is located underneath the form page. i.e:

- Form page location: `sitecore/content/site/home/contactus`
- Success page location: `sitecore/content/site/home/contactus/thankyou`
- Form location: `sitecore/system/modules/Web Forms for Marketers/site/form`

However the current behaviour is when the submit button is clicked the form page reloads, there is a delay for a good few seconds, then the success page is loaded.

Below is the log of the browser console upon submitting the form:

```
Navigated to https://site//contact-us/
Navigated to https://site//Contact-us/Thank-You
```

Any idea what's the reason behind this reload?

Comment: Can you confirm if the field "Is Ajax Mvc Form" field is checked on the form?

Comment: Try modifying ViewsFormEditorTemplatesFormModel.cshtml file and replace
if (Model.IsAjaxMvcForm)
with
if (Model.IsAjaxMvcForm && !Model.SuccessRedirect)

Comment: Clean(ish) install of Sitecore and WFFM? Any customisations?

Comment: I'll be damned ticking the box actually solved the issue :p. Even though I do remember testing it previously, went back to try that again now did it in two different environments and the extra reload is gone. Are there any implications to checking this box on the form?

Comment: A few but nothing relating to `successAction`, using the default `Sitecore.Forms.Core` library for those in `Sitecore.Forms.Configs`. Also it seems ticking the `Is Ajax Mvc Form` takes away the additional page reload. are there any implications to leaving that ticked on all the forms?

Comment: @Jawad glad it solved the issue :) pls mark it as solved so someone else can be benefited from it. 

this is what i see that checkbox used for 

if (Model.IsAjaxForm)
 {
   attributes.Add("data-wffm-ajax", true);

   if (!IsPost)
   {
     queryString.Add("wffm." + Constants.FormItemId, Model.Item.ID.ToGuid());
     queryString.Add("wffm." + Constants.Id, Model.UniqueId);
   }

   routeName = Constants.Routes.Form;
 }
 else
 {
   routeName = Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName;
 }

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1149)

Comment: @PeteNavarra Thanks for your moderation comment. Ticking the box actually makes the extraneous reload go away. But I was looking to find out what is it exactly that would trigger the page to reload when the request is not send as an AJAX request. that would be a complete answer to the question in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been confirmed. Ticking the `Is Ajax MVC Form` check box on the form itself gets rid of the extraneous reload upon submitting the form.

However the delay between submitting and getting a response might still be an issue and would need to be addressed separately.